# Rails: link each...do statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a neater way to do this in Rails?

```
tvs.each do |tv|
  tv.boxes.each do |b|
    b.templates.each do |t|
      puts t.name
    end
  end
end
```

I just want to loop through the `t.name` without three lines of `each` statements preceding it.

Comment: What is in the `tvs` variable? and in the `tv` variable and so on...

Comment: It's a collection of ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What will tv.boxes returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this which will do the same thing

```
tvs.flat_map(&:boxes).flat_map(&:templates).map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are tables from database?

you can use `joins`. I don't know exactly names of your tables and relations, but you need something like this:

```
Template.joins(box: :tv).where(tvs: {id: something} ).pluck(:name)
```